# Parallax CSS effect not supported in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have used a simple CSS parallax effect [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KarinaMcG/6pgb8/4/) which is working in all browsers except IE7 + 8.  Is there a work around or is it just not supported?

```
<h1>My Page</h1>
<h2>Flowers, Flowers, Flowers </h2>

<div id="slide4" class="slide" data-stellar-background-ratio="0" data-slide="4"> </div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slide" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" data-slide="2"> </div>

<h2>Some text goes here</h2>
<h2>Some text goes here</h2>
<h2>Some text goes here</h2>
<h2>Some text goes here</h2>
<h2>Some text goes here</h2>

#slide4 {background-image: url("http://ibmsmartercommerce.sourceforge.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Roses_Bunch_Of_Flowers.jpeg");
background-size: contain;
float: left;
margin-top:20px;
height: 450px;}

.slide {background-attachment: fixed;
height: 100%;
position: inherit;
width: 100%;}
```

Comment: `inherit` isn't supported in IE7 and `background-size` isn't supported in IE7 and 8.

Comment: _All_ browsers except IE 7 and 8?  So it's working in Netscape Navigator v1.0?  And what about Lynx? :)

Answer (score -1):

background-size is not available to IE8: http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

If you’re trying to use background-size: cover, check out this post: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

also you can use this polyfill for backgroud size support in ie 8

https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill